# When is the authenticity token generated for delete actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csrf

I understand that when you view the form for `new` and `update` actions, rails generate the authenticity token to protect from CSRF attacks, but when is this token generated when the action is `destroy` and therefore there is no form ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#csrf-countermeasures :

> To protect against all other forged requests, we introduce a required security token that our site knows but other sites don't know. We include the security token in requests and verify it on the server. This is a one-liner in your application controller, and is the default for newly created rails applications:
>
> protect_from_forgery with: :exception
>
> This will automatically include a security token in all forms and Ajax requests generated by Rails. If the security token doesn't match what was expected, an exception will be thrown.

Delete - when done without a form - is likely implemented as an `Ajax request` and is covered by `protect_from_forgery`.